# Deploying multiple projects (war) in jetty

Tags: jetty, solr4

I am using Solr which comes with Jetty by default. The `solr.war` is deployed using the following configuration in the `solr-jetty-context.xml` file

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath"><SystemProperty name="hostContext" default="/solr"/></Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/webapps/solr.war</Set>
  <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
  <Set name="tempDirectory"><Property name="jetty.home" default="."/>/solr-webapp</Set>
</Configure>
```

Now I want to deploy a custom html page say "`home.html`" on the same jetty server. How can I make sure that the "`home.html`" page and the `solr.war` both are deployed on jetty at the same time. I tried placing `home.html` in the webapps folder but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Put `home.html` into a .war named `root.war` and deploy. Your `home.html` file will be available at `http://.../home.html` while Solr will still be `http://.../solr/`.

For reference, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications.